# Trying to put a JCheckBox in a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, jcheckbox

So I have been working on this for 45 minutes now, and I can't seem to figure out why something so simple isn't working.  I have a pretty complex GUI and have gotten just about everything down in the layout the way I want it, but when I tried to make a `JList` of `JCheckBoxes` it completely didn't work.  So I simplified my problem to this test class here, maybe I'm doing something really stupid, but here's my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
public class TestGUI extends JFrame{
    public TestGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("TEST");
        JPanel outside = new JPanel();
        add(outside);
        outside.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JList<JCheckBox> checks = new JList<JCheckBox>();
        JCheckBox c = new JCheckBox("Check");
        checks.add(c);
        JScrollPane t = new JScrollPane(checks);
        add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGUI();
    }
}
```

When I run the GUI nothing appears...Just empty space, no check boxes...

Comment: [Concepts of Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) holds for all collection showing Swing components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. do not extend `JFrame` class unnecessarily.
2. Do not call `JFrame#setVisible(true)` before all components have
   been added.
3. Use Event-Dispatch-Thread/Intial Thread for UI components
4. you add `JPanel` outside, and then add `JScrollPane` on top of that
   I dont think that is what you wanted to do?

I was able to put together a short example for you which uses a custom `ListCellRenderer` to render `JCheckBox` in `JList`. It also uses `MouseAdapter` to allow checking and unchecking of `JCheckBox`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class JListTest {

    public JListTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("JList Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initComponents(frame);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        String[] strs = {"swing", "home", "basic", "metal"};

        final JList checkBoxesJList = new JList(createData(strs));
        checkBoxesJList.setCellRenderer(new CheckListRenderer());
        checkBoxesJList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        checkBoxesJList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int index = checkBoxesJList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                CheckableItem item = (CheckableItem) checkBoxesJList.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                item.setSelected(!item.isSelected());
                Rectangle rect = checkBoxesJList.getCellBounds(index, index);
                checkBoxesJList.repaint(rect);
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(checkBoxesJList);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private CheckableItem[] createData(String[] strs) {
        int n = strs.length;
        CheckableItem[] items = new CheckableItem[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            items[i] = new CheckableItem(strs[i]);
        }
        return items;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JListTest();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CheckListRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer {

    public CheckListRenderer() {
        setBackground(UIManager.getColor("List.textBackground"));
        setForeground(UIManager.getColor("List.textForeground"));
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus) {
        setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
        setSelected(((CheckableItem) value).isSelected());
        setFont(list.getFont());
        setText(value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}

class CheckableItem {

    private String str;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public CheckableItem(String str) {
        this.str = str;
        isSelected = false;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean b) {
        isSelected = b;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.kidslovepc.com/javatable/java-jlist-checkbox-simple.shtml

Comment: a) you only want to change the checkable selected state when the mouseEvent happens in the area of the checkBox (not the text) b) checkable shoud be observable so the model can listen to its changes c) with b) in place, there would be no need to manually call repaint

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize putting JCheckBoxes into a ScrollPane got so involved.  But thank you so much for the help and the tips, I'll be sure to clean up my actual GUI a bit more.  One more question though, the getListCellRendererComponent of your CheckListRenderer, is that what basically makes the check box appear?

Comment: @Keegan me neither but yes it is ( this only applies when displaying swing components in a `JList`) And thank you glad I helped. And yes `getListCellRendererComponent` is basically what makes it appear :)

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you for the great tips as always +1 :)